# .update and .updateAll not functioning as needed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am putting together an application on Composer that is very similar to the sample Bond network on the Playground. Part of my application requires removing outdated contracts on the date of expiry. The code therefore must grab all the contracts, find ones whose dates are less than the current, and change their `valid` field to `false`. Below is some code I run:

```
function SOD(sod) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.otc.LiveContract')
.then(function (contractRegistry){

    return contractRegistry.getAll();
})
.then(function (l){
    allContracts=l;
    //console.log('Curr List: ',allContracts);
    var q = new Date();
    var m = q.getMonth();
    var d = q.getDay();
    var y = q.getFullYear();
    var date = new Date(y,m,d);
    var arr=[];
    allContracts.forEach(function(contract) {
      //console.log('Contract Date: ',contract.contract.expiry);
      if (contract.contract.expiry<date) {
        //console.log('Checks Out');
        //console.log('Destroying: ',contract);

        arr.push(contract);
        //console.log('Return: ',x);
      } 
    }) 
return arr
}).then( function(arr){
    var factory = getFactory();
    new_arr=[];

    fLen = arr.length;
    for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
        var old_contract=arr[i];
        console.log('ISIN: ',old_contract.ISINcode);
        var new_contract = factory.newResource('org.acme.otc', 'LiveContract', old_contract.ISINcode);
        console.log('Entry: ',old_contract);
        new_contract.contract=old_contract.contract;
        new_contract.valid=false;
        new_arr.push(new_contract);


    } x=invalidate(new_arr);
});
```

Now, the code that generates the `new_arr` works well. I can inspect in Playground and I get the following log of `new_arr`:

[New Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv6Mi.png)

However, when either I call invalidate on on `new_arr` or I replicate that code inside `SOD`, the desired affect on the Registry does not occur. I don't get a `false` under the `valid` field. When I try to read in x in the debugger, I get the limp-wristed Promise response:

[Ugh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5BvD.png)

Here are my .cto and .acl files:

`//otc.cto`

```
    namespace org.acme.otc

    participant Trader identified by traderId {
      o String traderId
      o String name
      o Boolean marginThresh // margin meeting maintenance minimum
    }
    participant Administrator identified by adminId {
      o String adminId
      o Boolean tradingOpen 
    }

    enum Product {
      o OPTION
      o FUTURE
      o FORWARD
    }

    concept Order {
      o String traderID
        o Product productType
        o String asset // commodity? underlying? - may later need typing
        o Boolean buy
        o Double notionalAmount
        o DateTime expiry // only needs to specify date
    }

    concept Contract {
      o String buyerID // buyer/seller vs maker/taker?
        o String sellerID
        o Product productType
        o String asset // commodity? underlying? - may later need typing
        o Double notionalAmount
        o Double value
        o DateTime expiry
    }

    asset OpenOrder identified by ISINcode {
      o String ISINcode
        o Order order
        o Boolean valid
    }

    asset LiveContract identified by ISINcode {
      o String ISINcode
        o Contract contract
        o Boolean valid
    }

    transaction PlaceOrder {
      o String ISINCode
      o Order order
    }
    transaction SOD {
      o String adminId
    }
    transaction Test {}
```

`//permissions.acl`

```
  rule Issuer {
      description: "Allow full access to the issuer of a bond"
      participant(i): "org.acme.otc.Trader"
      operation: ALL
      resource(a): "org.acme.otc.OpenOrder"
      condition: (a.bond.issuer.memberId === i.memberId)
      action: ALLOW
  }

  rule Default {
      description: "Allow read access"
      participant: "org.acme.otc.*"
      operation: ALL
      resource: "org.acme.otc.*"
      action: ALLOW
  }

  rule SystemACL {
      description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
      participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
      operation: ALL
      resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
      action: ALLOW
  }

  rule NetworkAdminUser {
      description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
      participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
      operation: ALL
      resource: "**"
      action: ALLOW
  }

  rule NetworkAdminSystem {
      description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
      participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
      operation: ALL
      resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
      action: ALLOW
  }
```

I'm highly inexperienced in JavaScript, so the error could be minute. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
I am working through Paul's response here. My new code is below

```
/**
 * Start of Day Update
 * @param {org.acme.otc.SOD} sod - the sod transaction
 * @transaction
 */
function SOD(sod) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  //arr=pare();
  var aR=null;
  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.otc.LiveContract')
    .then(function (contractRegistry){
        ar=contractRegistry;
        return ar.getAll();
  })
    .then(function (l){
        allContracts=[];
        allContracts=l;
        console.log('Curr List: ',allContracts);
        var q = new Date();
        var m = q.getMonth();
        var d = q.getDay();
        var y = q.getFullYear();
        var date = new Date(y,m,d);
        console.log('Current Date: ',date);
        arr=[];
        allContracts.forEach(function(contract) {
          //console.log('Contract Date: ',contract.contract.expiry);
          if (contract.contract.expiry<date) {
            //console.log('Checks Out');
            //console.log('Destroying: ',contract);

            arr.push(contract);
            //console.log('Return: ',x);
          } 
        }) 
    return arr
    }).then( function(arr){
        var factory = getFactory();
        new_arr=[];

        fLen = arr.length;
        for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
            var old_contract=arr[i];
            console.log('ISIN: ',old_contract.ISINcode);
            var new_contract = factory.newResource('org.acme.otc', 'LiveContract', old_contract.ISINcode);
            console.log('Entry: ',old_contract);
            new_contract.contract=old_contract.contract;
            new_contract.valid=false;
            new_arr.push(new_contract);


        } 
    console.log(new_arr);
  });
  console.log("getting to update the records");
  return  aR.updateAll(new_arr);

}
```

However it doesn't work. The code never seems to reach the final `console.log`. The previous log works fine, and the new contracts inside of it are correct. Any thoughts on this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didn't see the `updateAll` code bit or know what function `invalidate(new_arr)` does  - so I'll post something similar but you get the gist - it works in Playground. Both `update` and `updateAll` work fine for me.

I've pasted working code below - just gave it a transaction / TP decorator from your namespace etc.

UPDATE:
(my original post I'll leave here - as it works) - I've also updated a working version of your second new code block - but with corrections, eg. you didn't reference objects correctly (like `ar` instead of what should be `aR`so it could never update the registry etc) and - you need to follow the JS promise chain, using the way you've done it - so I've added that code for you in 'ANSWER 2' below.). Also, probably best to declare `new_arr` to have global function scope and I've done that in my code.

```
/**
 * New script file
 */

/**
* A transaction processor function description
* @param { org.acme.otc.SOD } sod A human description of the parameter
* @transaction
*/

function SOD(sod) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

  var aR = null;

  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.otc.LiveContract')
  .then(function (contractRegistry){
     // return contractRegistry.getAll();
      aR = contractRegistry;
      return aR.getAll();
  })
  .then(function (l) {

      allContracts=[];
      allContracts=l;

      console.log('allContracts List is: ' + allContracts );

      var q = new Date();
      var m = q.getMonth();
      var d = q.getDay();
      var y = q.getFullYear();
      var datevar = new Date(y,m,d);
      arr=[];

      allContracts.forEach(function(contract) {
      console.log('Contract Date: ' + contract.contract.expiry);

      if (contract.contract.expiry < datevar ) {
      console.log('Checks Out - this contract needs fixing');
      console.log('Destroying: ' + contract);

      arr.push(contract);
      //console.log('Return: ',x);
      } 
    }) 
  return arr
  })
  .then( function(arr) {
      var factory = getFactory();
      new_arr=[];

      fLen = arr.length;
      for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
          var old_contract=arr[i];
          console.log('ISIN: ' + old_contract.ISINcode);
          var new_contract = factory.newResource('org.acme.otc', 'LiveContract', old_contract.ISINcode);
          console.log('Entry: ' + old_contract);
          new_contract.contract=old_contract.contract;
          new_contract.valid=false;
          new_arr.push(new_contract);


       }  // x=invalidate(new_arr);


   });

   console.log("getting to update the records");
   return  aR.updateAll(new_arr);
    //.then(function () {

       // return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.otc.LiveContract')
       //.then(function (contractRegistry){

       //  return contractRegistry.updateAll(new_arr);

    // });
   //});
}
```

ANSWER 2: UPDATED CODE using your 2nd code block

```
/**
 * Start of Day Update
 * @param {org.acme.otc.SOD} sod - the sod transaction
 * @transaction
 */
function SOD(sod) {  // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  //arr=pare();

  var aR=null;
  new_arr=[]; 

  return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.otc.LiveContract')
    .then(function (contractRegistry){
        aR=contractRegistry;
        return aR.getAll();

  })
    .then(function (l){
        allContracts=[];
        allContracts=l;
        console.log('Curr List: ',allContracts);
        var q = new Date();
        var m = q.getMonth();
        var d = q.getDay();
        var y = q.getFullYear();
        var date = new Date(y,m,d);
        console.log('Current Date: ',date);
        arr=[];
        allContracts.forEach(function(contract) {
          //console.log('Contract Date: ',contract.contract.expiry);
          if (contract.contract.expiry < date) {
            //console.log('Checks Out');
            //console.log('Destroying: ',contract);

            arr.push(contract);
          //console.log('Return: ',x);
          } 
        }) 
    return arr
    }).then( function(arr){
        var factory = getFactory();

        //new_arr=[];

        fLen = arr.length;
        for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
            var old_contract=arr[i];
            console.log('ISIN: ',old_contract.ISINcode);
            var new_contract = factory.newResource('org.acme.otc', 'LiveContract', old_contract.ISINcode);
            console.log('Entry: ',old_contract);
            new_contract.contract=old_contract.contract;
            new_contract.valid=false;
            new_arr.push(new_contract);


        } 
       console.log("New Array is now " + new_arr);
  })
   .then(function () {

      console.log("getting to update the records");
      return  aR.updateAll(new_arr);
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Worked through your edits, the code never seems to reach the last `console.log` however and the contracts aren't updated. The updated code is in the post, I think its exactly what you have. Any thoughts on this now?

Comment: hi, see ANSWER 2 above for explanation, why your new code doesn't work. I've left my original answer (it works), and a new answer (your revised code basically).